# Paypal refund service throws TRANSACTION_REFUSED error

Tags: node.js, paypal-sandbox, paypal-ipn, paypal-rest-sdk, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to use the refund service of paypal. I'm using the sandbox environment to test. I make the payments (subscription based) using the sandbox and for some reason, paypal takes almost a day to execute the payment. Our system works like: 
1) Create a subscription based plan 
2) Pay for that subscription 
3) Paypal returns a billingAgreementId along with the return URL, save that Id
4) Since, paypal takes a lot of time, use the Webhook Simulator to trigger "Payment Sale Completed" event type and do the payment.

So, since the simulator sends the same dummy sale_id each time (and would throw invalid ID error), I couldn't test the refund API (shown below), so I used the transaction_id (which is same as sale_id) from the sandbox environment and used it statically for the refund. But it throws an error even then, although I have used a valid sale_id. The error looks like this:

```
httpStatusCode: 400
response:
debug_id: "83878fa1bdb27"
httpStatusCode: 400
information_link: "https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/payments/#errors"
message: "Request was refused.You can not do a partial refund on this transaction"
name: "TRANSACTION_REFUSED"
```

My code:

```
if (refundServiceResult.refundAmount > 0) {
      //CALL PAYPAL REFUND SDK
      var data = {
          amount: {
            currency: "USD",
            total: refundServiceResult.refundAmount
          }
        },
        // saleId = body.resource.id;
        saleId = "88M48196CV276711X";
      let refunded = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        paypal.sale.refund(saleId, data, (error, refund) => {
          if (error) {
            throw new Error(error);
          } else {
            console.log("Refund Sale Response");
            console.log(JSON.stringify(refund));
            resolve(refund);
          }
        });
      });
      console.log("Refunded Response", refunded);
```

I did some research and found that this can happen if the currency is not listed in the sandbox settings but I'm using USD everywhere and the "Payment Review" option is also toggled to Off. But I'm still getting this error. What can be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

So, I was using the transaction_id(sale_id) of the buyer instead of seller. In the sandbox environment, you can find the transaction_id for the latest payment in both seller as well as buyer's accounts. You should use the seller account's transaction_id for refund.